# Could not connect to SMTP host: ..., port: 25?

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

How can I diagnose a "Could not connect to SMTP host: ..., port: 25 ?" issue?  My exception is listed below.  I can telnet to port 25 on that server, so something is there.  How do I determine if smtp is running on port 25.

```
telnet mail1.us.test.com 25

>220 RELAY02-mail1.us.test.com
```

**exception**

```
 2016-07-11 10:18:40.322 83741 [Camel (externalDataCamelContext) thread #0 - file://C:/TEMP/mfc_load] ERROR o.a.c.p.FatalFallbackErrorHandler - \--> New exception on exchangeId: ID-USSPD0BWDP1-26096-1468246639804-0-5 
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail1.us.test.com, port: 25
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282) ~[mail.jar:1.4]
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370) ~[mail.jar:1.4]
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275) ~[mail.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.mail.DefaultJavaMailSender.send(DefaultJavaMailSender.java:111) ~[camel-mail-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailProducer.process(MailProducer.java:49) ~[camel-mail-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:303) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.FatalFallbackErrorHandler.processNext(FatalFallbackErrorHandler.java:42) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.deliverToFailureProcessor(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:766) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:273) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:303) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor.process(FilterProcessor.java:58) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:334) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:303) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:85) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:334) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:303) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:334) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:571) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:504) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:213) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:96) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:334) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:303) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:122) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:61) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:334) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:303) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:81) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:334) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:303) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:336) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:189) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:155) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:142) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:92) [camel-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232) ~[mail.jar:1.4]
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189) ~[mail.jar:1.4]
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250) ~[mail.jar:1.4]
```

Comment: There is a way to test a SMTP server from command line. Maybe you find it useful: http://www.vsysad.com/2013/10/testing-smtp-server-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, The solution was to start tomcat with this flag: -`Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`